# Webpack Image for React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, webpack

I've read through most posts, but still can't figure out why my application won't display an image.  I'm using webpack 4+ in a React application.

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: ['html-loader'],
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s*)css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000,
    },
  },
};
```

I then call an image JSX tag in one of my components `<img src={require('../assets/GGGlogo.png')} />` where the assets folder is also contained within my src folder.  When I run the webpack dev server, everything compiles successfully and the app starts.

However, my chrome console outputs: `GET http://localhost:8080/app/b561359832a3836146dd3f42233e77f7.png 404 (Not Found)`

When I run my dev script to make a dist folder with the bundle.js and image, the above hash is indeed the image I want.  Why is there a 404 error when trying to find the image?

Comment: is the image with that hash name placed inside an 'app' folder? If not, have you tried setting a `publicPath` in your file-loader config? e.g `{ loader: 'file-loader', options: {publicPath: 'app'}, }`

Comment: Yup, I've set the public path option in my webpack config file, but definitely a good suggestion.  We were able to figure it out by just utilizing our Nginx proxy to make a call to a URI with that hashed image.